# Azure AD: Your sign-in was successful but you don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I created an account on Azure Active Directory.

It works fine on my end and can able to login using the account I recently created.

I send the test account to the other user which is based on UK and it showing an error below.

I am residing in PH, and he is residing in UK.

> Your sign-in was successful but you don't have permission to access
> this resource
> [image]

Below is the API Permission on our App Registration in Azure AD.

[image]

Anyone knows on what particular settings do I need to change anything?

Comment: can [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-location) help you?

Comment: Click on more details and add the IP region on conditional access policy.  So it will allow the other region users. [Refer this Document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-azure-management.md)

Answer (score 0):

> Azure AD: Your sign-in was successful but you don't have permission to access this resource:

- From Azure AD through portal, get to
   `Security > Conditional Access > Named locations.`
- Try adding a new location.
- If you know the precise IPv4 address ranges that make up that country or region, you can add them as IP ranges for that particular country/region  and save it.

  *Note:-*  Adding unknown areas is an option if you select Countries/Regions.

[image]

*References:*

1. [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/location-condition)
2. *You can also create a conditional access policy as per industry standards* [Steps to achieve the same](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-azure-management.md).